# SocketIO: Access both io and socket instance in separate service

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have implemented socket.io in an express server. Everything works, but I would like to avoid having a long socket script in my main file. I have thus created a separate service to handle socket logic in another file:

main.js:
`io.on("connect", SocketManager(io))`

socketManager.js:
`const SocketManager = (io) => {io.on("connect", ()=> do stuff}`

But when doing so, I can only use io instance. Socket is undefined, which is quite unfortunate given I must access it to achieve specific tasks. Sadly, I can't just pass socket as a second argument to SocketManager. How to fix this?

Comment: Well, this `io.on("connect", SocketManager(io))` is messing you up because that's where the socket is passed and you're not using it.  You need to be passing a "function reference" so you can get the callback.  You're just executing a function and not responding to the connect event at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ignoring the `socket` that is passed into the `connect` event so you're missing your opportunity to use the actual newly created socket.

To fix, change this:

```
 io.on("connect", SocketManager(io))
```

to this:

```
 SocketManager(io)
```

All you want to do there is initialize your socket manager and pass it the `io` instance and let it listen for the `connect` event itself.

Then, in your `SocketManager` code, you want to pay attention to the `socket` argument that is passed into the `connect` event.  So, change this:

```
 const SocketManager = (io) => {io.on("connect", ()=> do stuff}
```

to this:

```
 const SocketManager = (io) => {
     io.on("connect", (socket) => { 
         // do stuff using newly connected socket in here
     });
 });
```